# Extract script element with embedded JSON from page

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to get the store locations of a specific state from this webpage, I can only retrieve `content_type : text/html`, how can i get the json section since i know it's there looking at the html file?

```
import requests
import json
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Content-type': 'application/json', 
    'Accept': 'text/plain'
}

response = requests.get('https://www.sephora.com/happening/storelist', headers=headers)
```

The results is as follows

```
200
text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

now of course iv'e tried `respone.json()` , it throws an exception,

```
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Reading the output  `full = json.dumps(response.text)` results in a very messy text, with a portion written as a dictionary only

`<script id=\"linkStore\" type=\"text/json\" data-comp=\"PageJSON \">{\"page\": ....etc`

**Edited post: working code**

it worked through parsing html using bs4 and then getting the dict according to a tag under text/json

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    script_tag = soup.find('script', {'type': 'text/json'})  
    if script_tag:
        specific_content = script_tag.text
        json_data = json.loads(specific_content)
    else:
        print("Script tag not found.")
```

Comment: You change the url to point to the API endpoint that actually returns you the json of the locations. Open your browser's dev-tools,  reload the page, see what requests page does, see the responses of the requests and then you change the url you are using to the one that returns the data you need ..

Comment: You need to use beautifulsoup to parse `<script id=\"linkStore\"` element

Comment: @OneCricketeer so you're suggesting parsing html, then cutting out the json format part ? I tried something similar, but the problem persists with resultant string, it has so many errors, and doesn't load as dict but as str

Comment: @rasjani I have used .json as an endpoint, can't find the specific states data I need, it's like not the full data in the page

Comment: that website  gets your location data (either via GeoIP or via request to your browser to share its location)  - this is quite evident when you open the page in browser ..  Did you feed that information to the location endpoint ?

Comment: That address you've given always returns HTML content, not plain JSON, so yes, you need to parse it... Whatever example you followed was not using sephora website, and probably used a JSON-only API... `requests` will never only return you JSON data

Comment: @rasjani by feed you mean requests.post?

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for replying, i was looking for a way without parsing, so you suggest to parse html with beautiful soup and then extract the json part? .... I tried this manually as a text file containing only the dictionary part, still generates an error with json.loads and treats as str only

Comment: You don't need a text file. Please [edit] your post with your attempt

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the URL you are requesting doesn't return the response in a `json` format. Instead it returns a `plaintext/html`. Therefore you are getting the error.

You can access the content of the response using `.content` property.

```
response = requests.get('https://www.sephora.com/happening/storelist', headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

You can refer to the documentation here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content

Comment: from what I understand, r.text is a string and r.content is in byte format, but either way , the problem is with the result, json.loads(response.content/text) produce the same error